# How to count photos on my FANPAGE wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photos, facebook-wall

I gave an access to fans to upload photos to FANPAGEs wall. How can I count posted photots?
I am too young in FB.apis :-(
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via the Graph API you can get the Photos connection off of the Page object.

See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

You can play around here:  http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

1. Get `/me/accounts`
2. Click one of the page IDs that show up that has some photos.
3. Add /photos after the page ID and click Get `/{pageId}/photos`

Comment: Hi, DMCS!

https://graph.facebook.com/{pageId}/photos gives me photos POSTET BY ME
 but not from fans :-(

Comment: You should use a "page" access token when calling the get to `/{pageId}/photos`.  You can get the page access token from the `me/accounts` results.

Answer (score 1):

I've just read http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

> An individual photo as represented in the Graph API.
>
> To read the 'photo' object you need
>
> any valid access_token if it is public
>   user_photos permission to access photos and albums uploaded by the user, and photos in which the user has been tagged
>   friends_photos permission to access friends' photos and photos in which the user's friends have been tagged
>   To publish a 'photo' object you need
>
> a valid access token
>   publish_stream permission
>   With that granted, you can upload a photo by issuing an HTTP POST request with the photo content and an optional description to one these to Graph API connections:
>
> https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/photos - The photo will be published to an album created for your app. We automatically create an album for your app if it does not already exist. All photos uploaded this way will then be added to this same album.
>
> https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos - The photo will be published to a specific, existing photo album, represented by the ALBUM_ID. Regular albums have a size limit of 200 photos. Default application albums have a size limit of 1000 photos.

PAGE or APP creates OWN XLBUM which can access the same way: https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos

But there is 1000 photos limitation!